# MariaDb ColumnStore stored procedure returns Expected to read 4 header bytes but only received 0

Tags: c#, .net, mariadb, mariadb-columnstore

I m calling a stored procedure using the following code:

`dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sqlCommand.ToString());`

I have the following Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user11`@`%` PROCEDURE `UpdateDimDateEntity`(IN DimDateKey INT,
     IN FullDate DATE,
     IN DayName NVARCHAR(50),
     IN DayOfWeek SMALLINT)
BEGIN
 UPDATE DimDate
    SET
        FullDate = FullDate,
        DayName = DayName,
        DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek       
    WHERE DimDate.DimDateKey = DimDateKey;
END
```

The return type of `ExecuteSqlRaw` is int (4 bytes) and I read at this [article](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/columnstore-create-procedure/) that MariaDb ColumnStore accepts definition of stored procedures with only input arguments and a single SELECT query does not return anything and that I suspect that it does not return anything the method expects a 4 byte message it does not receive it and it fails.

How can I call a SP from C# without waiting for number of affected rows?

Comment: ADO.NET's core interface is `DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`, and that already returns an `int`. There is no way for a conforming .NET driver to not produce something here. It need not be the number of affected rows if that's not available, but it can't error out on it either, that would be a bug. This is therefore not likely to be your issue.

Comment: But if it is expecting a 4 byte message and because the DB engine does't return anything wouldn't that be an issue?

Comment: That would be a bug in the MariaDB driver. I rather suspect the problem may be that it's not gracefully reporting a timeout or internal server error -- even if the procedure returns nothing, the DB should at least send a packet acknowledging that the command was executed (otherwise it wouldn't know when to return from the call), and if that's not happening it should mean the connection was closed by the server. Check if you get any errors executing the procedure manually, or with a command-line tool.

Comment: Note that the "4 bytes" spoken of here are not an `int` value produced by the command, but the packet length stored in the header. Receiving 0 bytes there typically means that either the connection was closed, or there is a problem parsing a previous packet sent by the server (for example, because it lacks fields it expects) which trips up the driver. In that sense it could also be a version mismatch.